# Surprising c-style cast

Tags: c++, casting

I am refactoring our code-base, where I have the following code (simplified):

```
template <typename T>
class TVector3;

template <typename T>
class TVector4;
  
template <typename T>
struct TVector4
{
    TVector3<T>& V3()                   {   return (TVector3<T> &) *this;                       }
    const TVector3<T>& V3() const       {   return (const TVector3<T> &) *this;                 }
};
   
template <typename T>
struct TVector3
{
    template <typename U>
    constexpr TVector3(const TVector4<U>& v) noexcept { }
};

typedef TVector3<float> Vec3f;
typedef TVector4<float> Vec4f;

struct RGBA
{
    Vec4f rgba;
    operator Vec3f() const              {   return rgba.V3();       }
};
```

clang warns me about `returning reference to local temporary object` (https://godbolt.org/z/ccxbjv771). Apparently `(const TVector3<T> &) *this` results in calling `TVector3(const TVector4<U>& )`, but why ?

Intuitively, I would have expected `(const TVector3<T> &)` to behave like reinterpret cast, or if at least the cast would have looked like `(const TVector3<T>) *this` (without `&`) it would kind of make sense to me that the compiler picked that constructor call for conversion.

Another simpler example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { };

struct B
{
    B(const A& ) { std::cout << "B(const A&)" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    (const B&) a;
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `B(const A&)` (https://godbolt.org/z/ocWjh1eb3), but why ? I am converting to `const B&` and not to `B`.

Comment: You might want `*(TVector3<T> *) this` in which case the c-style cast is on a pointer type which has no user defined constructors to interfere. Or just `reinterpet_cast`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It prints `B(const A&)`, but why ? I am converting to `const B&` and not to `B`.

The type of `a` is `A`, it can't be bound to `const B&` directly. It needs to be converted to `B` via `B::B(const A& )` firstly; then the converted temporary `B` is bound to `const B&`. (Lvalue-reference to const could bind to temporaries.)

Comment: Interesting, it makes sense that it first has to convert to `B` in order to be able to bind `A` to `const B&` and hence it calls the constructor. And to develop the point further, it is forced to do this, because standard mandates that it first has to attempt `static_cast` before attempting `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 7):

It calls the constructor because such are the rules of c-style cast:

> [cppreference:](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) When the C-style cast expression is encountered, the compiler attempts to interpret it as the following cast expressions, in this order:
>
> - a) `const_cast<new_type>(expression);`
> - b) `static_cast<new_type>(expression)`, with extensions: pointer or reference to a derived class is additionally allowed to be cast to pointer or reference to unambiguous base class (and vice versa) even if the base class is inaccessible (that is, this cast ignores the private inheritance specifier). Same applies to casting pointer to member to pointer to member of unambiguous non-virtual base;
> - c) `static_cast` (with extensions) followed by `const_cast`;
> - d) `reinterpret_cast<new_type>(expression);`
> - e) `reinterpret_cast` followed by `const_cast`.
>   The first choice that satisfies the requirements of the respective cast operator is selected, even if it cannot be compiled (see example). If the cast can be interpreted in more than one way as `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`, it cannot be compiled.

`static_cast` is chosen because it considers the constructors. **Please do not use c-style cast, you see the rules are not so easy and it forced you to make a question about them.**

> Intuitively, I would have expected (const TVector3 &) to behave like reinterpret cast

You wouldn't want that, it would break strict aliasing. But if you remove the constructor, it **will happily do that** as per d).

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A { };

struct B
{
    B(const A& ) { std::cout << "B(const A&)" << std::endl; }
};
struct C
{
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    const B& temp1 = (B&) a;// Ctor, copy, prolonged-life good.
    const B& temp2 = (const B&) a;// Ctor, copy, prolonged-life good.
    B& dangling_temp = (B&) a;// Ctor, copy, no prolongment->dangling ref, BAD.
    (const C&) a;// REINTERPET_CAST
    //(const C) a;// Compiler error, good.
    (const C*) &a;// REINTERPET_CAST
    return 0;
}
```

But `a` is not a `B`? If you really really want it to be `B`, use `reinterpret_cast`(but don't) or `bit_cast` explicitly. The sane thing is to attempt to make a copy if possible. It creates a new temporary `B` and binds it to `const B&`. Had you stored it into `const B& b`, it would prolong the temporary's lifetime, making the code safe.

Comment: `You wouldn't want that, it would break strict aliasing.` what do you mean with this ? `Vec4f` is just one float more than `Vec3f`, so it should be more or less safe to reinterpret cast from `Vec4f` to `Vec3f`, no ?

Comment: @jcxz That might be true, but C++ aliasing rules are quite strict. For `Vec4f* obj = reinterpret_cast<Vec4f*>(ptr);` to be valid, there must **live** a `Vec4f` object at `ptr` address. If there isn't one, dereferencing `obj` is undefined behaviour. The fact they have the same layout is irrelevant. Correct approach is to use `std::memcpy`, compilers can often elide those copies.